# Is this an issue in kernel or application?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, kernel

## I am getting a kernel crash:

Unable to handle kernel paging request for data at address 0x00000000

Faulting instruction address: 0x8003337c

Oops: Kernel access of BAD area, sig: 11 [#1]

MPC8536 DS

Modules linked in: dsrmux(P) dsrnet(P) ds1631 iom_cpld ltc1840 moc_ipsec

moc_memdrv musart mvKernelExt mvPpDrv pca9505 pca9548 pca9554 phoenix_cpld sfp

NIP: 8003337c LR: 8003342c CTR: 801c7604

REGS: aefd1b10 TRAP: 0300   Tainted: P            (2.6.29.6)

MSR: 00021200   CR: 28004828  XER: 20000000

DEAR: 00000000, ESR: 00000000

TASK = aefc5f10[1052] 'INOS-MSR' THREAD: aefd0000

GPR00: 8003342c aefd1bc0 aefc5f10 81801988 00000003 00000001 00000000 aefd1c18 
GPR08: 00000068 00000000 af207400 81800060 00000068 11e8c26c af692640 00000000 
GPR16: 804b1408 aefd1c80 00000000 000006d2 aee06e80 af6926d8 00000000 0000092e 
GPR24: 00000003 00000068 00000001 00000001 81801988 fffffff4 0000773a aefd1bc0 
NIP [8003337c] __wake_up_common+0x38/0xb4

LR [8003342c] __wake_up+0x34/0x50

: Kernel Crash reported at 0x386e618d, Call Trace:

==========

This happens when flooding happens towards the device. 
I need help in getting started on this. The box runs an application (The application runs as root) with many threads and one of the threads (https server) processes the packets. After a brief while (say 3 minutes) the console prints this and restarts.

I am not sure if this is an issue in kernel  (scheduler?) space or an erring application/thread issue? On the surface, it looks to be a kernel issue. How to proceed?

Comment: This is kernel issue (application alone cannot cause kernel to crash). If device is involved into that crash report, you can send this report to the author of the device driver, or fill report at his bugtracker.

Answer (score 0):

This is a NULL pointer dereference error that happens in the kernel.
It could be a faulty device driver, or a kernel generic bug.